# outlook: different credentials for incoming and outgoing mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to configure outlook 365 with an incoming and an outgoing server. The incoming server A is:

```
A:
   Server:   imap.some_domain.nl
   User:     userid1
   Password: password1
```

and an outgoing server B:

```
B:
    Server:   smtp.provider.nl
    User:     userid2@provider.nl
    Password: password2
```

For some reason, every time I send outgoing mail Outlook uses the credentials for the incoming server, fails and opens a pop-up to correct the userID/password. A few minutes later, when a mailcheck is done, that is done with the outgoing credentials that I just filled in, it fails and I get a pop-up for the credentials again.  That works, until the next outgoing mail, when the process repeats itself.

I ticked the box for saving my credentials.

Is it possible to use different credentials for incoming and outgoing servers, and if so, how?

Comment: Not an answer, but a temporary workaround: use a third-party tool such as Thunderbird, which has separate logins and passwords for inbound and outbound email.

Comment: I know. But that is not really an option here.

Comment: are you using gsuite?

Comment: Not in this context. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook do have options for that like below, but I could not test about it due to lack of email accounts like that.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible!

nagivate to control panel and open the MAIL(outlook) application there.
add your account here and it will appear in outlook.
[control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d60MI.png)
[add email account here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGCr.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).